# Current line blame in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, git-blame

There's a feature in VS Code's GitLense extension that I'm trying to find the equivalent for with Atom. It's the [current line blame](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/#current-line-blame) feature.

I have installed the Atom [blame](https://atom.io/packages/blame) package which works, but is slow to load for large files with a large number of commits on them.

Is there anything in Atom or any package that will show blame for just the current line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, just didn't search hard enough.  I just found [this package](https://github.com/joelgardner/git-line) which is fairly close.  While it's not inline (displays via tooltip) it is fast, and has a link to the commit on the web as a bonus.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  And the question itself is definitely good to have closed as well.  Now I know :)